# Lowering opacity on non-hovered elements

Tags: javascript, svg, opacity

I have twelve svg paths. All of which have 100% opacity.

I would like to hover hover one path keep this at 100% and change the other 11 paths opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed CSS in you SVG:

```
#paths:hover path {
     opacity:50%;
}
#paths path,
#paths:hover path:hover {
     opacity:100%; /* the default value */
}
```

```
<g id="paths">
    <path ... />
    <path ... />
    ...
</g>
```

Comment: what if all each of the 12 paths are groups of 3 paths

Comment: It should also work with subgroups. If not, please post your DOM in your question.

Comment: thanks. i was just being a moron. missed a collon like a fool.